# specifying path of an image file in mvc

Tags: jquery, xml, html, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I am working on a MVC project in Visual Studion using C#, Razor, HTML, Jquery and CSS. The problem is in the part where we have to generate a library XML file based on the choices entered by the user. One of the choices is for selecting an image/icon. 
I just want to do one simple thing-

1. User selects a file on his computer which he wants to be used as icon.
2. the file location gets stored in the xml
3. while deserealizing the library.xml file, the file location is read and the image file is copied into the projects folder.

Problems-

1. In doing all of this I'm getting confused, because currently localhost is acting as the server, so there is no difference in uploading of files from client vs server.
2. If it was the case that the file has to be specified from client's computer, it would mean uploading it to someplace on server. But this has some security implications.

Can anyone suggest me a workaround to these problems. I am new to all this and didn't find questions that look at the problem from this angle. Would be very grateful for any help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                 var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload"), fileName);
                 file.SaveAs(path);
```

Upload is the folder name in the application where your image will be stored.

Comment: I have to write the code in the view part of mvc using jquery and html5, so I have an <input> element of type="file". Can you suggest something that I can do in the View part

Comment: because I have written the complete code for library generation in html5 and jquery, what you have suggested would work in 'controller' part no doubt, but I dont know how to pass the control back and forth between the 'controller' and 'view'.

Answer (score 1):

```
Add this in view file and add the first code in controller


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
    <b><u>File Upload in MVC3 By Using Razor</u></b>
        Select Image
        <input type="file" name="file" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="Command" /><br />
    </div>
    <div>
    @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
}
```

Comment: After the uploading is done, will the control come back to the View page and continue the form from where it was left off? Because in my code the form fields selected by the user are picked up and feeded into string variable, which is saved on the computer on click of a button. Wouldn't these two things interfere?

Comment: Yes in the action method of controller write, Return("ViewName"); at the end. The ViewName will be name of the view which contains your view code.This will redirect the control back to view side.

Comment: are you sure it is Return("ViewName"); ?

Comment: I used return RedirectToAction("ViewName","ControllerName"); 
Also, applied breakpoints on this function, and found that on the click of button, the action method is not getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial solved my problem:

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/WKNQ120113-How-to-upload-a-file-in-MVC4.html